# Kinesis Advantage Keyboard VS ergoMagic vertical keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I'm really experiencing pain in my wrists. I am looking for a new keyboard to minimize this problem. I tried to search for reviews of both the Kinesis Advantage keyboard and the ergoMagic Vertical keyboard, but I couldn't find any actual comparisons between the two.

The Kinesis Advantage has a really 3D design, but I still lack info about it compared to a real vertical position keyboard. As I see it now, the Kinesis advantage really looks comfortable, but still its position is very horizontal, which seems like it would be uncomfortable for me. On the other hand, vertical keyboards like the ergoMagic Comfort don't really look that nice either.

Anyone have experience with both?

Comment: It might be your typing style. Try single spacing and using less "..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a Kinesis Freestyle with an Ascent accessory. I use it completely vertical, 90 degrees to the table, as far as I am aware this arrangement is unique. I had a hurting wrist. Now I don't. That is all to say. It's not empty propaganda: stand up and just relax, now check the position of your hands! See, that's their natural position. A  split keyboard (like the Freestyle) helps already keeping your hands closer to their natural position but a vertical keyboard keeps them where they should be. Superb. Because the Ascent is adjustable you can get used to it in about 7-10 days by going up one step a day.

As I travel to various Drupal events with this monstrosity, other Drupalers bought the keyboard as well and as far as I am aware, they are also happy.

Comment: Update: now I use a Matias Ergo Pro vertically. Setup with photos at https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=79810.0 same forum has people mounting this keyboard on table tripods, seat armests and more.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that your experiencing is a pinching of the radial or ulner nerves, which travel from the hand through the grooves in your elbow, and up your arm, over the shoulder and up your neck.

The pinch can occur in your wrist, elbow, shoulder, or neck.

If the pinch is occurring in the wrist or elbow, a compression wrap/guard on the wrist will most likely solve the problem. This is a wrap for the wrist that is made out of a taut stretchy material, you should feel moderate pressure when you put it on, but loosen if blood flow restriction occurs. Get something that has support on the pad of the wrist for use while typing. Mine has a small bean bag. I find the bean bag more comfortable than the gel types. This will correct posture on any keyboard. And you can take it with you anywhere. You can also wear it at any time, even when your not at a keyboard and you'll get increased healing benefits.

Do not use a rigid wrap while typing (this kind has a metal bar that forces your wrist into a natural position). You can buy a rigid wrap for compression while sleeping, but be careful to not hit your partner while asleep.

Second thing to try is pairing the wrist wrap with an elbow wrap. Same thing, compression type.

If having both still doesn't solve the problem, try looking for a knot along the inner arm muscle. These knots can pinch the ulnar nerve. If you find any knots, massage them out. The process will hurt, because after the nerve pinch subsides there will be a momentary *increase* in pain.

If there are no knots in your arm, the problem is in your shoulder or neck. First try adjusting your seating position. Ensure that knees and elbows are at 90 degree angles, feet are flat, and most important, shoulders are at a natural position, not raised like in the "I don't know" expression. Back straight, and good lower back support (they call this lumbar support). Your spine is S shaped (front to back), and you need to support this with your posture. Viewing angle of monitor should be level with your head or below. Not above.

If perfecting your posture doesn't work, you'll need to visit a doctor because the pinch is in your shoulder or neck. You'll need support in working out a shoulder pinch, and if it's a neck pinch you may need surgery. Consider this a last resort. Patients of surgery usually see no difference from people who avoided surgery as early as five years. So these painful episodes in your life are either temporary, or recur even after surgery.

A recap:

If pinch is in wrist or elbow, $10 can solve your problem, and it's $10 you can always use, no need to buy multiple keyboards and waste $100s. If this doesn't work, look for a knot in the arm. Massage out.

If the pinch is in your shoulder or neck, ensure you have good seating posture, then visit a doctor. Try both chiropractor and a neural specialist. They take different approaches, but always consider surgery as a worst possible option.

Experience:

I'm not a doctor, but I've had multiple problems with my ulnar nerve, and I've talked with doctors quite a bit. I also have a disc that's torn, so I've worked out problems with my leg as well. I'm experienced in using multiple remedial therapies, and have a good feel for what works and what's just from blood-sucking vampires using bogus theories. The threat to your health is real. The outside of my left hand is, from what I can tell, permanently numb.

Update: After half a year of practicing all the above, the feeling in my hand returned.

Answer (score 1):

I have three of the Kinesis Advantage keyboards. I've had severe tendonitis in the wrists in the past. These Keyboards saved my career. The comfort level and even more important the ergonomics is unsurpassed. The orientation of the keys are in straight lines and not staggered. The huge typing advantage and comfort of this seemingly small modification will makes itself felt because I am not able to type for hours on end without any problems. I could not do so on regular keyboards. The keys are low force and of the mechanical type and don't bottom out so you won't experience any of the jarring when using membrane type keyboards. The customer support for these keyboards is excellent. Don't be put off by the cost. the cost is nothing as compared to saving your career. RSI related trauma is very real and dangerous. Please don't neglect it as it only gets worse over time if ignored.

On another important note I suggest good physical therapy and posture (bad posture is responsible for computer related wrist issues). I had therapy from Suparna Damany in Allentown, PA (a world-class therapist and author in computer related trauma). These measures combined with having a great keyboards will heal your wrist.

All the best,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the ergoMagic, but I've been a happy Kinesis Advantage user for more than 7 months now. Though I've thankfully not been afflicted with any RSI/CTS and related problems, I'm noticing a substantial increase in typing comfort, especially after many-hour programming sessions. The gently curved profile of the Advantage and proper spacing of the keyboard "wells" allow the hands to occupy a more relaxed and natural position. Unlike traditional keyboards with a single group of keys, the wrists on an Advantage are kept mostly straight, keeping the ulnar nerve from long-term pressure. One additional modification that I've been using (on all my keyboards, including on the laptop) was to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. I'm a heavy Emacs user, and this step was a natural choice. The Advantage is rather expensive (though still much cheaper than, say, Maltron), but I would say that it's worth every dollar and more. I bought mine on Massdrop for little over $200, which was a real bargain, but I've been so happy with my typing ever since. Plus, you get an additional perk that people passing by your desk will go "What the...?" :). Anyway, this is the best keyboard I've used so far, so I can honestly recommend it.